# How to map keyboard key to run a console command?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this cheap bluetooth multimedia controller with 5 keys (play, prev, next, vol up, vol down). It's all connected and key presses are recognised:

```
[root] [~] # showkey
kb mode was UNICODE
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode 164 press
keycode 164 release
```

How do I go from here? How do I make this 164 key press to run "mpc toggle" command? This is a console-only Linux machine. No any kind of a X window system.

Answer (score 0):

Its doubtful will work for your bluetooth multimedia controller, but to find out keys with needed for terminal try `cat -et` and pressing and copy the printable character shown in screen and modify samples given below.

**bash-shell**

using `/etc/inputrc` file or local `~/.inputrc`, input rc will look something like

```
# don't forget to input default
$include /etc/inputrc

"\e[1;5A": "\C-uamixer set "Master" 10%+\C-j" # C-up
```

**zsh-shell**

you can use *bindkey* and add it into rc file! in your case up volume up will be!

```sh
# for zsh-shell
bindkey -s '^[[1;5A' '^Uamixer set "Master" 10%+^M' # C-up
```

**Others**

Desktop Environment binding (Xfce, GNOME, KDE) refer to its manual.

Comment: Unfortunately cat -et shows nothing. I gotta mention that this is an embedded device (Orange Pi) and I don't have a direct display nor keyboard connected to it. The only options I have are serial console and ssh. Any other ideas? If the bluetooth controller is pairing properly and the key presses are being recognised, I'm sure this is possible but not sure how.

Comment: i guess its not possible with bash, might have to write the input event listener